# JavaScript - array, object - How can I streamline this code

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

How can I streamline this code ?
I think it might have better way to refactor .

```
const aa = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
const bb = { first: 0, second: 1, third: 2 }
const cc = { ...bb }

cc.first = aa[cc.first]
cc.second = aa[cc.second]
cc.third = aa[cc.third]
```

Comment: Is this really what you want, or just some contrived example?  What are you generally trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.reduce()` and `Object.entries()` methods:

```js
const aa = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
const bb = { first: 0, second: 1, third: 2 }

const cc = Object.entries(bb)
                 .reduce((r, [k, i]) => (r[k] = aa[i], r), {});

console.log(cc);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that still works after adding or removing an item from aa or bb, without need to change your code.

```
const aa = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
const bb = { first: 0, second: 1, third: 2 }    
const cc = {};

for(var key in bb)
   cc[key] = aa[bb[key]];
```